# Stream webm to node.js from c# application in chunks

Tags: c#, node.js, ffmpeg, socket.io, video-streaming

I am in the process of learning about streaming between node.js with socket.io and c#.

I have code that successfully records the screen with ffmpeg, redirects it StandardOutput.BaseStream and stores it into a Memorybuffer, when i click stop in my application it sends the memorystream as a byte array to the node.js server which are storing the file so the clients can play it. This are working just fine and here are my setup for that:

**C#**

```
bool ffWorkerIsWorking = false;
private void btnFFMpeg_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    BackgroundWorker ffWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
    ffWorker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
    ffWorker.DoWork += ((ffWorkerObj,ffWorkerEventArgs) =>
    {
        ffWorkerIsWorking = true;
        using (var FFProcess = new Process())
        {
            var processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                FileName = "ffmpeg.exe",
                RedirectStandardInput = true,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                UseShellExecute = false,
                CreateNoWindow = false,
                Arguments = " -loglevel panic -hide_banner -y -f gdigrab -draw_mouse 1 -i desktop -threads 2 -deadline realtime  -f webm -"
            };
            FFProcess.StartInfo = processStartInfo;
            FFProcess.Start();

            byte[] buffer = new byte[32768];
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                while (!FFProcess.HasExited)
                {
                    int read = FFProcess.StandardOutput.BaseStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                    if (read <= 0)
                        break;
                    ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
                    Console.WriteLine(ms.Length);
                    if (!ffWorkerIsWorking)
                    {                                
                        clientSocket.Emit("video", ms.ToArray());                                 
                        ffWorker.CancelAsync();
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
    ffWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

**JS (Server)**

```
socket.on('video', function(data) {
    fs.appendFile('public/fooTest.webm', data, function (err) {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log('File uploaded');
    });
});
```

Now i need to change this code so it instead of sending the whole file it should sends chunks of byte arrays instead of the whole video, and node will then initially create a file and then append those chunks of byte arrays as they are received. Ok sound easy enough, but apparently not.

I need to somehow instruct the code to use a offset and just the bytes after that offset and then update the offset.

On the server side i think the best approach is to create a file and append the byte arrays to that file as they are received.

On the server side i would do something like this:

**JS (Server)**

```
var buffer = new Buffer(32768);
var isBuffering = false;
socket.on('video', function(data) {
    //concatenate the buffer with the incoming data and broadcast.emit to clients

});
```

How am i able to setup the offset for the bytes to be sent and update that offset, and how would i approach the way of concatenating the data to the initialized buffer?

I have tried to write some code that only reads from the offset to the end and it seems like this is working although the video when added up in node is just black:

**C#**

```
while (!FFProcess.HasExited)
{
    int read = FFProcess.StandardOutput.BaseStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    if (read <= 0)
        break;
    int offset = (read - buffer.Length > 0 ? read - buffer.Length : 0);
    ms.Write(buffer, offset, read);
    clientSocket.Emit("videoChunk", buffer.ToArray());
    if (!ffWorkerIsWorking)
    {                                
        ffWorker.CancelAsync();
        break;
    }
}
```

**Node console output**

[image: Bytes read]

**JS (Server)**

```
socket.on('videoChunk', function(data) {
    if (!isBufferingDone) {
        buffer = Buffer.concat([buffer, data]);
        console.log(data.length);
    }
});

socket.on('cancelVideo', function() {
    isBufferingDone = true;
    setTimeout(function() {
        fs.writeFile("public/test.webm", buffer, function(err) {
            if(err) {
                return console.log(err);
            }
            console.log("The file was saved!");
            buffer = new Buffer(32768);
        }); 
    }, 1000); 
});
```

**JS (Client)**

```
socket.on('video', function(filePath) {
   console.log('path: ' + filePath);
   $('#videoSource').attr('src',filePath);
   $('#video').play();
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: Updated the question with some new code.

Comment: any update on this.